# Getting all data from website which use lazy loading

Tags: web-scraping, lazy-loading, yql

Need to get all data from website, 
i am using tool, which generates me JSON:

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+html+where+url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tipsport.cz%2Fkurzy%2Fdnes%22

But the website where i am getting data use lazy loading, so there are not all data promptly. The rest of data are shown when you scroll at the end of preload datasets.

Or is there any way how to get all data from website which use lazy loading? I was trying cUrl but without effects.

Thanks for advice